# All the five digit numbers in which each successive digit exceeds its predecessor are arranged in the increasing order of their magnitude.

Tags: combinatorics

All the five digit numbers in which each successive digit exceeds its predecessor are arranged in the increasing order of their magnitude.The $97$th number in the list does not contain the digit
$(A)4\hspace{1 cm}(B)5\hspace{1 cm}(C)7\hspace{1 cm}(D)8$

---

The question is demanding the numbers of the type of numbers as $''24567''$.Such numbers should start from either 1,2,3,4,5.
But i do not know how to calculate the $97$th number.

Comment: Can you tell how many such numbers there are in total? There is one fast and easy way that would also hint you toward a relatively quick way to find number $97$ on the list.

Comment: For your info, the $97^{th}$ number on the list is 24678. (By brute force).

Comment: How do you get this?@AlainD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selecting an admissible number means selecting a five element subset of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

There are ${8\choose4}=70$ numbers of the form $1x$ and ${7\choose4}=35$ numbers of the form $2x$. Since $70<97<70+35$ the first digit is $2$.

There are ${6\choose 3}=20$ numbers of the form $23x$ and ${5\choose 3}=10$ numbers of the form $24x$. Since $70+20<97<70+20+10$ the first two digits are $24$.

There are ${4\choose2}=6$ numbers of the form $245x$. Since $70+20+6=96$ the number we are after is the first number of the form $246x$, which is $24678$. It follows that (B) is true.